# Automatically redirect incoming mail in Outlook 2016

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there a way to automatically redirect incoming messages? I tried creating a rule but found nothing that says redirect it to people or public group.

If I have 3 mailboxes : A, B & C.

1. A sends message Hello to B.
2. B automatically redirect Hello to C using A's mail address in sender.
3. C is able to reply directly to A without having to change the recipient.

I only found forward it to people or public group as the closest available actions but not what I need since C needs to manually re-select A as recipient.

[This site](https://www.technipages.com/automatically-forward-email-outlook) and [this one](https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/how-to-forwardredirect-your-outlook-mail-to-another-email-account/) shows that such an option exists. But it does not appear on my rule list.

**EDIT :** I couldn't find Run a script at first. But, [this site](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlook-2016-run-a-script-rules/) enabled me to recover the option by editing a registry key. I'll try using a macro with a rule. However, is it possible to enable other options with such a method?

Comment: That site shows that the option to *forward* emails exists and not *redirect*.

Comment: @thims I'm talking about the second option under the selected one in step 5.

Comment: What type of Outlook account do you use (Exchange/Office365/IMAP/POP3/...)?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot see the "redirect" option in your rules? As is suspected by thims, it seems that "redirect it to people or public group" is not available to IMAP or POP3 accounts.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the desired functionality, you'll need to either create a VBA macro and fire it in a rule or use a third-party Outlook add-in.

Comment: Can you help me with either solution?